# Turning attribute table in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I want to show the attributes of the column "PHK_text" as a row on top of the table. "PHK_text" has ten different terms and all of them should be shown on top of the table as a new column. Now there are 339 objects in the table and in the end there should be 51 because the column "ortsteile_b" has 51 different terms. The new table should show all ten terms of "PHK_text" for all 51 terms of "ortsteil_b".

Which tools can I use to get a result?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [Pivot Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) tool?

Comment: I don´t have the license for the Pivot Table tool. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could manually approximate Pivot Table by adding fields and then using some kind of if-else statement in the Field Calculator. Not the cleanest solution, but it could get the job done (especially if this is a one time processing issue).